# Xamarin CalendarContract

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating a calendar in xamarin forms using DependencyService and creating events with this code:

```
ContentResolver cr = ((Activity)Forms.Context).ContentResolver;
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
var uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri;

values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, Id);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, title);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, description);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, hour, minute));
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, hour, minute));
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllDay, allday ? "1" : "0");
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, hasalarm ? "1" : "0");
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "GMT+" + zone + ":00");
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "GMT+" + zone + ":00");

cr.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, values);
```

What I exactly want is to add those events to a self-created calendar. How do I create a calendar first and then add the above events into it?

Comment: I know that in iOS user can have multiple calendars to insert events into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of creating a new calendar on the device, taken from [Source](http://silverspoted.blogspot.com/2013/10/creating-calendar-in-xamarin-monodroid.html):

```
            var uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri;
            ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, AccountName);
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, CalendarContract.AccountTypeLocal);
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.Name, "My Calendar");
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarDisplayName, "Silverspot");
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarColor, Android.Graphics.Color.Red);       
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.OwnerAccount, AccountName);
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.Visible, true);
            val.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.SyncEvents, true);
            uri = uri.BuildUpon()
                .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CallerIsSyncadapter, "true")
                .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, AccountName)
                .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, CalendarContract.AccountTypeLocal)
                .Build();
            var calresult = ContentResolver.Insert(uri, val);
```

Comment: An what has Account Name supposed to be and he not telling me how i add the events into it and post is from 2013

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.SyncColumns.html#ACCOUNT_NAME.  And you already have the code for adding an event to a calendar in your post.

Answer (score 0):

For the layout I use CalendarView and a ListView to show the events for the selected date.
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.CalendarView/
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ListView/

To populate the events I use Adapter. These are my function that are called when the date changed.

```
var eventsUri = CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri;
string[] eventsProjection = {
                CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title,
                CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart,
                CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description
             };
string selection = CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart + " >= ? AND " + CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart + "<= ?";
string[] sourceColumns = {
                    CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title,
                    CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart
                };
int[] targetResources = { Resource.Id.eventTitle, Resource.Id.eventStartDate };
var adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, Resource.Layout.EventListItem, cursor, sourceColumns, targetResources);
adapter.ViewBinder = new ViewBinder();
listview.Adapter = adapter;
```