# Android Device Calendar with DependencyService not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, calendar

I made a Xamarin.Forms app, and want to save the appointments automatically to device calendar without any notice.

I found the microsoft solution: [Xamarin.Android Calendar][1]

I dont know what is the problem, i dont get any exception, the program working well, but i cant see any saved appointment to device calendar. I gave read and Write permissions too

*(Before i have tried StartActivity version too, what worked, but if i send 30 appointment from the app, the user going to be crazy if the device calendar is displayed 30 times)*

Please give me any advice, what wrong?

```cs
        public async Task<bool> AddAppointment(List<TestItem> xys)
        {
            var items = TestItem.GetAppointmentsToDeviceCalendar(xys);

            foreach (CalendarEvent item in items)
            {
                var uri = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, ToCalendarEvent(item));
            }
            return true;
        }

        private ContentValues ToCalendarEvent(CalendarEvent item)
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarTimeZone, TimeZone.Default.DisplayName);
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "local");
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, TimeZone.Default.DisplayName);
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, item.Name);
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, item.Description);
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation, item.Location);
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(item.Start.Year, item.Start.Month, item.Start.Day, item.Start.Year, item.Start.Minute));
            cv.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(item.End.Year, item.End.Month, item.End.Day, item.End.Hour, item.End.Minute));
            return cv;
        }

        long GetDateTimeMS(int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)
        {
            Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);

            c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfMonth, day);
            c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hr);
            c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, min);
            c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Month, month);
            c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Year, yr);

            return c.TimeInMillis;
        }

  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/calendar
```

Comment: Did the Android calendar control awakened? How did you consume the method of 'CalendarDeviceHelper' class in Xamarin.Forms? Could you post the related code? And you could add a breakpoint to check if the function code is called.

Comment: Hello. I updated the description. Its very strange. I debuged, i see only one strange thing. I installed the sample demo Microsoft calendar app, and when i start i see all the dates in My Device calendar category, but none of other calendar see the appointments. Maybe its hidden?

Comment: To perform an operation as a sync adapter `CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` should be set to true and `CalendarContract.SyncColumns.ACCOUNT_NAME` and `CalendarContract.SyncColumns.ACCOUNT_TYPE` must be set in the Uri parameters. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33291608/11083277

Comment: The AccountName and AccoundType are used to async the settings to device, you need to add them yourself. Check the links:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.SyncColumns#constants_1 https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084644?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: I dont know, after i modified CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri to CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri (because i written before) all is good, but still all the events are hidden, not showing up. I try to write all of the calendars, i create a new one too, but all events are hidden, i dont know why.

Comment: I create a basic demo to test the feature and it works well. The event was added to the calendar of the device, you could refer to the code.

Comment: Hi, any updates? If this solution help you to solve the issue, please mark it as the answer. If you are facing some issues while implementing, try to post the particular error with the corresponding codes here.

Comment: Hi. Yes, i changed the insert with bulkinsert, and everything works fine. Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an operation as a sync adapter `CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` should be set to **true** and `CalendarContract.SyncColumns.ACCOUNT_NAME` and `CalendarContract.SyncColumns.ACCOUNT_TYPE` must be set in the **Uri** parameters.

Try to change the code as below:

```
var uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri;

uri = uri.BuildUpon()
    .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CallerIsSyncadapter, "true")
    .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, AccountName)      
    .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, CalendarContract.AccountTypeLocal)
    .Build();

Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(uri, ToCalendarEvent(item));
```

Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33291608/11083277

**Update:**

I create a basic demo to test the feature and it works well. The event was added to the calendar of the device, you could refer to the code.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private static string CALENDER_URL = "content://com.android.calendar/calendars";
    private static string CALENDER_EVENT_URL = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
    private static string CALENDER_REMINDER_URL = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

    private static string CALENDARS_NAME = "test";
    private static string CALENDARS_ACCOUNT_NAME = "test@hello.com";
    private static string CALENDARS_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.android.test";
    private static string CALENDARS_DISPLAY_NAME = "hello-test";

    long account_id;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        //requestedPermission: you need request the permissions at runtime

        account_id = addCalendarAccount(this);

        Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(TimeZone.Default);
        c.Set(CalendarField.DayOfMonth, 15);
        c.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 10);
        c.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 0);
        c.Set(CalendarField.Month, Calendar.July);
        c.Set(CalendarField.Year, 2020);

        addCalendarEvent("title", "description", c.TimeInMillis);
    }

    public long addCalendarAccount(Context context)
    {

        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.Default;
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.Name, CALENDARS_NAME);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, CALENDARS_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, CALENDARS_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarDisplayName, CALENDARS_DISPLAY_NAME);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.Visible, 1);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarColor, Color.Blue);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.SyncEvents, 1);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.CalendarTimeZone, timeZone.ID);
        value.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.OwnerAccount, CALENDARS_ACCOUNT_NAME);

        Uri calendarUri = Uri.Parse(CALENDER_URL);
        calendarUri = calendarUri.BuildUpon()
                .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CallerIsSyncadapter, "true")
                .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, CALENDARS_ACCOUNT_NAME)
                .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, CALENDARS_ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                .Build();

        Uri result = context.ContentResolver.Insert(calendarUri, value);
        long id = result == null ? -1 : ContentUris.ParseId(result);
        return id;
    }

    public void addCalendarEvent(string title, string description, long reminderTime)
    {
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.Instance;
        mCalendar.TimeInMillis = (reminderTime);//set the start time
        long start = mCalendar.Time.Time;
        mCalendar.TimeInMillis = (start + 10 * 60 * 1000);//set the end time
        long end = mCalendar.Time.Time;

        ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

        eventValues.Put("title", title);
        eventValues.Put("description", description);
        eventValues.Put("calendar_id", account_id); //int the account id
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, start);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, end);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, 1);
        eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "Asia/Shanghai");
        Uri newEvent = this.ContentResolver.Insert(Uri.Parse(CALENDER_EVENT_URL), eventValues);
        if (newEvent == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I succesfully got the accountname. But always i get  "column calendar_id is invalid" I checked, and  i seen the CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri can only use if i create or modify the whole calendar. But if i use your solution changed the CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri to CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, is success, but the events are not showing, so the result is the same